# save text fields to an Array (and pull data from the Array) when using treeview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, treeview

Ok, I have a treeview which I am using to display a number of nodes. I wish to attach data (three textbox fields) to each node but I do not want to show it in the tree. I wish to save the data to a string[] Array if possible. I want the data in the boxes to save to the Arrays when I click on a new node in the tree and pull the information from the Arrays for the new node.

For some reason the code I have does not work. It doesn't save the information and sometimes it just shows random data in the text boxes as I click about. The code is:

```
    These are global variables within the form:
    string[] desc1;
    string[] desc2;
    string[] desc3;

 private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

          // save the entered text into the local variables
        desc1[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index] = textBox4.Text;
        desc2[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index] = textBox5.Text;
        desc3[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index] = textBox6.Text;

    }

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

        // update labels
        label23.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString();
        label24.Text = (treeView1.SelectedNode.Index + 1).ToString();

        // enable all textbox fields
        textBox4.Enabled = true;
        textBox5.Enabled = true;
        textBox6.Enabled = true;

        // clear all textbox fields
        textBox4.Text = null;
        textBox5.Text = null;
        textBox6.Text = null;



        // if parent is selected then show as unselected - if not update text fields
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString() == "Parent Name")
        {
            label23.Text = "Unselected";
            label24.Text = "Unselected";
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // show the information from the array in the text fields
            textBox4.Text = desc1[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index];
            textBox5.Text = desc2[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index];
            textBox6.Text = desc3[treeView1.SelectedNode.Index];
        }

    }
```

Anyone have an idea of what I can do? I have trawled google now for 24hours with no luck.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TreeNodes` have a `Tag` property that you can use to attach any sort of data that you would like.

You would use it like this:

```
// To set the data:
myTreeNode.Tag = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };

// To read the data:
var data = myTreeNod.Tag as string[];
```

Comment: Brilliant, I gave this a blast, saving the data to Tags on the previous listview (where I got the information to populate the treeview) and its now working. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are not initalized.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the code for this, however I assure you they are :)

Comment: The problem, in addition to the fact that you must pass into the array the EventArgs.Node.Index, is that you never save anything. This happens because before selecting you insert new values: the values you see in textboxes are the new values, not the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your references to `SelectedNode` to be `TreeViewEventArgs.Node` instead.

Code example:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{

    // update labels
    label23.Text = e.Node.Text.ToString();
    label24.Text = (e.Node.Index + 1).ToString();

    // etc etc...
}
```

Comment: @RHodgett: sorry, I didn't make myself clear.  Hopefully my code example helps clear things up.

Comment: Thank you, that runs but it still doesn't solve my problem of binding the data. I am thinking about giving up on the treeview and using a listview instead.