# Delphi Prism : Replacement for TreeView AddchildObject function

Tags: .net, treeview, replace, delphi-prism, addchild

I am in the process of migrating software for win32 to .NET and currently working with TreeView control in Delphi Prism. So far I am able to add parent nodes and child nodes to the TreeView. However, I would like to know if there is replacement for AddchildObject function for Delphi Prism TreeView. If not, how would you do it?

It seems there is very little information online about this.

Comment: The MSDN documentation of WinForms is very comprehensive. There are many tutorials for WinForms. Not much for Prism but you just need to get used to reading C# and writing Pascal. to reading C# and writing Pascal. Also tag it delphi otherwise you won't get many views.

Comment: @David I do exactly that - mostly read C# documentation and try to apply it to pascal. If it doesn't work or have no clue what I am doing, then I would search for answer online or books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this question may not get answered by the fellow programmers in here and I feel that this is an important question for any programmers doing Delphi Prism. So, I decided to answer the question myself instead of deleting it, since I found the answer for it in another StackOverflow question. However, my question and their question is different but require the same answer.

I wrote a quick and simple delphi prism sample to show how to use treeview and to be able to store and retrieve objects in the treeview node.

Here is my Treeview example

```
namespace TreeViewExample;

interface

uses
  System.Drawing,
  System.Collections,
  System.Collections.Generic,
  System.Windows.Forms,
  System.ComponentModel;

type
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for MainForm.
  /// </summary>
  MainForm = partial class(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
  private
    method MainForm_Load(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
    method treeView1_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
  protected
    method Dispose(disposing: Boolean); override;
  public
    constructor;
  end;

  theclass = class
  thestr:String;
  public
  constructor;
  end;

implementation

{$REGION Construction and Disposition}
constructor MainForm;
begin
  //
  // Required for Windows Form Designer support
  //
  InitializeComponent();

  //
  // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
  //
end;

method MainForm.Dispose(disposing: Boolean);
begin
  if disposing then begin
    if assigned(components) then
      components.Dispose();

    //
    // TODO: Add custom disposition code here
    //
  end;
  inherited Dispose(disposing);
end;
{$ENDREGION}

constructor theclass;
begin
  thestr:='Testing Treeview.';
end;

method MainForm.MainForm_Load(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
var topnode:treenode;
    theObject:theclass;
begin
  theObject:=new theclass;
  treeview1.BeginUpdate;
  topnode:=treeview1.Nodes.Add('node1');
  topnode.Nodes.Add('no data node');
  topnode.Nodes.Add('data node').Tag := theObject;
  topnode.Expand;
  treeview1.EndUpdate;
end;

method MainForm.treeView1_Click(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
  if treeview1.SelectedNode.Text='data node' then
    MessageBox.Show(theClass(Treeview1.SelectedNode.Tag).thestr);
end;

end.
```

Here is the link to the question.

[save text fields to an Array (and pull data from the Array) when using treeview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874756/save-text-fields-to-an-array-and-pull-data-from-the-array-when-using-treeview-i)